# Messages - Signs me out of facebook everytime laptop sleeps or screen turns off

Tags: messages, facebook, ichat

After turning the laptop on and logging in (into my macbook air) I am prompted for a password for facebook. I am signed onto two different gchat accounts just fine but not facebook.

Even after entering my password again I have a text sent to me from facebook saying to using a certain string of numbers as my password instead of my actual password.

I do have two step authenitcation on facebook, could that be the culprit? (although I have two step authentication for my google accounts also..)

I'm on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.4)

Comment: You should use the random generated strings as your application password for Messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log into Facebook, click on the Gear for Preferences, then go to Account Settings, then choose Security. Under Security, you can create App Passwords, which are application specific passwords you can use where two step authentication won't work. Create a new one for Messages, then use that as your Password to log into Facebook in Messages.